# DatePicker Angualar Material, Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem when i get the date from database.I get date in the string format from my web service, then i like to show to the input of my datepicker, but the date is not showing in my field. When I console the birthday come like this 02/04/1997 00:00:00. How can i format dhe date to datepicker format?

This is my html

```
 <div class="mb-24" fxLayout="row">
              <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="client.Birthday" formControlName="Birthday" placeholder="Ditëlindja" [matDatepicker]="picker" tabindex="3">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

This is my apiService when i get the list of client including birthday

```
  Client(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this._http.get<Client[]>('http://localhost:1636/BOXService.asmx/Client');
  }
```

And this is my form in file .ts

```
 createClientForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      Birthday: [this.client.Birthday],
```

This is my adapter

```
const dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat == "input") {
      return moment(date).format(dateFormat);
    } else {
      return date.toDateString();
    }
  }
}

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { day: 'numeric',month: 'short', year: 'numeric' }
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' },
    dateA11yLabel: { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
  }
};
```

Please can anyone help me? How can i format the date to fill my date picker field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), the behavior depends on which adapter you use. The `NativeDateAdapter` can't be used in your case because of the non-standard string format returned by your database. You should try with `MomentDateAdapter` instead.

Comment: i am using a costum adapter that extend NativeDateAdapter, and moment for format

Comment: @SerxhioIsufaj then give a try to my answer. It works with `NativeDateAdapter`

Comment: Yes it actually swaps day and month, and thus doesn't work for days > 12... My answer is wrong. I think you should use `MomentDateAdapter` because native JavaScript `Date` is very limited when it comes to input string format

Comment: i will try with MomentDateAdapter, yes my issue is that swap day with mont